# Passing null to NumberFormat.simpleCurrency in flutter app

Tags: flutter, null

I am using NumberFormat.simpleCurrency to format dollar amounts in my flutter app. It works great if trxns.contractPrice is not null. When it is null I get the following error:
The getter 'isNegative' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isNegative

Here is the code snippet:

```
TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                  '\nPrice: ${NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(trxns.contractPrice) ?? 'n/a'}\nStatus: ${trxns.trxnStatus ?? 'n/a'}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                )
```

I have not been able to find anything for this error. Can anyone please help me with how to deal with nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that `traxns` value is not null, then check its property or method `contractPrice` is not null. Right now, you're getting null for one of those things and an exception is being thown by the `format` method from `NumberFormat`. Once possiable example is:

```
TextSpan(
    text:'\nPrice: ${trxns!.contractPrice == null ? 'n/a' : NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(trxns.contractPrice)}\nStatus: ${trxns!.trxnStatus ?? 'n/a'}',
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.blueGrey),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a `null` check for the `contractPrice` before format

Sample:

```
Text(
'\nPrice: ${(contractPrice != null) ? NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(contractPrice) : 'n/a'}',
)
```